# Keras not being imported

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pycharm

I was trying to run this code, first time using Tensorflow API in Python. Donwloaded latest version of tensorflow and pip through terminal. However, when I attempt to import from keras subpackage, an error is returned

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Input
```

````
ImportError: cannot import name 'pywrap_tensorflow' from partially initialized module 'tensorflow.python' (most likely due to a circular import) (/Users/macbook/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py) ```
````

Comment: Try prefixing those libraries with `tensorflow.`, so for example, the first import would be `from tensorflow.keras.models import Model`. Then do the same with the rest.

Comment: You may follow this [pattern](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model): `import tensorflow as tf` then `model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)`